# MySQL AFTER UPDATE in a specific column UPDATE timestamp in same row

Tags: mysql

I want to update the timestamp 'lastpageview_at', when the pageviews increases. I think I'm close but I always get a syntax error, does anybody know why or have an other solution?

My trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_lastpageview BEFORE UPDATE ON shortlinks
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF OLD.pageviews <=> NEW.pageviews THEN
     SET NEW.lastpageview_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
    END IF;
  END;
```

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `shortlinks` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shortlink_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pageviews` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastpageview_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `shortlink` (`shortlink`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=84 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It's a  Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inequality operator is either `!=` or `<>` not `<=>`

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER Update_lastpageview BEFORE UPDATE ON shortlinks
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF OLD.pageviews <> NEW.pageviews THEN
     SET NEW.lastpageview_at = NOW();
    END IF;
  END;$$
```

Comment: Still an error: 
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4"

Comment: can you please check again